# Makefile - How to target all matching files?

Tags: makefile

```
    CC = g++49

#General Flags
CFLAGS =

#debug flags
CFLAGS +=

#Target Liker Flags
CFLAGS +=


TARGET  = ../game

INCDIR += -I
LIBDIR += -L
LIBS += -l


##############################################

INCDIR += -I
LIBDIR += -L
LIBS += -l  
##############################################
CPP_FILE =


OBJDIR =../../Object's
CPPOBJS = $(CPP_FILE:%.cpp=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)

default: $(TARGET)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    @echo compile $<
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCDIR) -c $< -o $@

$(TARGET): $(CPPOBJS)
    @echo linking....
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBDIR) $(CPPOBJS) $(LIBS) -o $(TARGET)
```

Soo this si my makefile  .
I want to find all .cpp files and compile.
Without their full name specified in CPP_FILE
Example :
CPP_FILE : test.cpp main.cpp slow.cpp scan.cpp

I want something like  CPP_FILE = *.cpp

It is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make provides a wildcard function for this very purpose.

```
CPP_FILE = $(wildcard my_dir/*.cpp)
```

Comment: Can you attach your entire Makefile and possibly directory structure? You'll need to make sure that the <my_dir/> in my example is correct based on your structure.

Comment: SOLVED : CPP_FILE = $(wildcard *.cpp) Like this, thanks